# Can "considerable distances" be an adverb?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I came across these sentence:

> Even modest cattle herds required plenty of land and considerable mobility. **To acquire such land often required moving herds considerable distances, even from summer to winter pastures.**

By grammar analysis I think "considerable distances" should be an adverb, but it looks noun to me, I find in dictionary that "long-distance" can be an adverb but not "considerable distances".

Can we paraphrase "adverb phrase"(not sure how to name the grammar of adverb long-distance) to whatever we want? Or considerable distances is not an adverb here?

Comment: They are two separate words unlike "long-distance". Considerable would be an adjective, and distances, a noun.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh But how is "moving herds considerable distances" possible? It's "Verb Noun Noun", two nouns occur consecutively.

Comment: Well first of all, there is a mistake in your question, 'long-distance' is an adjective. 'Long distances' preceded by a verb would depict it as an adverb. In that case, 'considerable distances' (in this case) would be an adverb-phrase, perhaps someone else might confirm it?